# yii active record lazy load

Tags: php, yii

Yii 1.1 powered app. I have models: CustomerAddresses and CustomerAddressTypes. In database, there are table customer_addresses with field customer_address_type_flags. It means that address has many types (legal, physical, etc..). Flag was created via binary OR operation like:

```
address_type_flags = 1 | 2 | 8; //1,2,8 - address_type_id values.
address_type_flags // 11
```

In CustomerAddresses active record I wrote such relation:

```
// CustomerAddresses.php (extends CActiveRecord)
...

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'AddressTypes' => array(
              self::HAS_MANY
            , 'CustomerAddressTypes'
            , ''
            , 'on' => 'AddressTypes.customer_address_type_id & 
                       Addresses.customer_address_type_flags <> 0'
        )
    );
}
```

I need to get instance of CustomerAddresses model in some code part. I successfully do it thus:

```
$customer_addresses = CustomerAddresses::model()
    ->with('AddressTypes')
    ->findByPk( 1 );
```

If I am using lazy load, I have got error:

```
$customer_addresses = CustomerAddresses::model()->findByPk( 1 );
// .. some code here ..
$customer_addresses->AddressTypes; // now related records will be loaded!
// ...and error has been received.
```

UPDATE. full error text:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Addresses.customer_address_type_flags' in 'where clause'. The SQL
>   statement executed was: SELECT
>   `AddressTypes`.`customer_address_type_id` AS `t1_c0`,
>   `AddressTypes`.`customer_address_type_name` AS `t1_c1` FROM
>   `customer_address_types` `AddressTypes`  WHERE
>   (AddressTypes.customer_address_type_id &
>   Addresses.customer_address_type_flags <> 0)

I found temporary solution:

```
$customer_addresses = CustomerAddresses::model()->findByPk( 1 );
// .. some code here ..
$types_mask = $customer_address->customer_address_type_flags;
$customer_address->AddressTypes = CustomerAddressTypes::model()->findAll(
    'customer_address_type_id & :customer_address_type_mask <> 0',
    array(':customer_address_type_mask' => $types_mask)
);
// works good, but too much extra code than correct lazy loading operation..
```

How can I use active records with related lazy loading correctly in my case?

Comment: Maybe `Addresses` is `CustomerAddresses`. Because it might not be the correct table name, because it does not have `customer_address_type_flags` as the error says.

Comment: @tpb, thanks for answer, but this is not problem which disturbs me to use AR lazy loading. I updated description of the question...